# Can stove grates be repainted?

Tags: gas, range, cast-iron

I did a very dumb thing and put my cast iron gas stove grates in the oven during a short (2 hour) self-cleaning cycle. Not only did I melt off the rubber feet but the iron is now gray and ashy looking which won't come off with a scrubby. I tried to purchase new ones but the cost is prohibitive. (I did buy replacement rubber feet which were ridiculously priced too). Has anyone had luck with painting grates with high temp paint?  Any other suggestions? Thanks!

**UPDATE 5/22** Before attempting to paint the grates, my husband rubbed them vigorously with fine steel wool, which removed the white ashy film. Although the tops are still a bit worn from daily use, at least the white film and greasy spots are gone and the grates look almost new.  I also replaced the rubber feet.  Thank you to those who responded.

Comment: people have done it - Make Sure you are really serious with the prep work - you know how they call those kinds of people that do something to the n'th degree - do the prep like that see my answer. When you finish mark the answer - maybe post a pic of your results.Good Painting - Cheers.

Comment: I put the cast iron grates in the self-cleaning oven once a year for Passover cleaning. With the previous stove the rubber feet melted - though not every time! - and replacement for those tiny little pieces was ridiculously expensive. But the new stove (still Kitchenaid, but newer design) doesn't have the rubber feet, so problem solved.

Comment: I would be concerned of chemicals released by any paint and absorbed by food. Select your paint very carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use something other than your box store hi temp paints if you want really good results. They are more like Hi-temp Coatings than they are paints. Before Painting you will need to do a really [thorough cleaning](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/refinish-stove-grates-58938.html) of them. Your preparation work is the HARDEST PART and the MOST important part of a good durable paint job. Anybody can squeeze a spray can - the prep work makes all the difference.  Take your time in the cleaning and PREP and you will have results as good as or better than a 'professional'.

A couple suggestions I have for you is to purchase something meant for hi-temperatures 500 to 1500 degrees

http://www.stovepaint.com/ .. although this says their paint is not for cooking surfaces or direct flame contact.

https://www.kbs-coatings.com/XTC.html